# Check and start system tray icon application

Tags: c#, .net

How do I check and start tray icon application? 
I want to start tray icon application from a windows service. Before starting, I need to check whether my tray application is already exists in tray icon and i need to start if it is not.

Comment: Windows services are not supposed to interact with the UI (that is, they are supposed to be running whether a user is logged in or not). Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service must know the process name of your app, then check if such a process already exists. If not- it should start a new process.

Your "TrayApp" on the other hand will then be responsible for putting itself into the system tray (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) and doing whatever work needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 seperate apps.

Your service which does the work, and the system tray app, which basicly subscribes to an event and calls methods on the service.

If you give us some more details we can advise on how best to approach this.

incidently, it is possible to have the service running under an 'Interactive Account' but its bad practice, and needs a lot of checks to ensure it'll work in all senarios.